# IntelliJ Idea GUI Forms: Null Layout

Tags: java, user-interface, intellij-idea, form-layout

Hey all, I'm migrating from Netbeans to IntelliJ. Now I'm trying to create a GUI form, and, unlike Netbeans, IntelliJ doesn't let you use a "Null Layout". Is there any way to put JComponents inside of a JFrame without using some wierd layout?

Sorry if I'm using incorrect terminology--hope you understand my question :)

Comment: This is a good thing that it doesn't let you use a "null layout". This is another reason to learn how to use layout managers so you are not dependent on the code generated by the IDE you happen to use. Spend time learning Java and not the IDE and your skills will work in any environment.

Comment: now I see--IntelliJ does the whole GUI thing differently than Netbeans. It's just something I have to get used to :\.

Comment: "Is there any way to put JComponents inside of a JFrame without using some wierd layout?"  Use any of the non-weird layouts.

Answer (score 0):

If you want null layout in IDEA (which is not recommended anyway), you can use the [JFormDesigner](http://www.formdev.com/).